# jQuery DateInput Destroy

Tags: jquery, date

Using the jQuery tools DateInput API found at

http://flowplayer.org/tools/dateinput/

I need to toggle an input box in between a normal input box, and a box used for a date input control.

I have no problem using the following to toggle the dateinput calendar on:

```
$('#value').dateinput({selectors:true, max: endDay(new Date()), yearRange:[-10,5] });
```

The problem I am having, is when I need to toggle the input box back to normal, and not have it be a dateinput, I cannot. For example, I would imagine there would have been an API call such as the following:

```
$('#value').dateinput('destroy');
```

Does anybody know what I can due to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace it with a new input via [`.replaceAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceall/) or [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/).

```
$("#value").replaceWith("<input>");
```

Comment: Haha damn, the simple answer is probably better here, yes.  Unless of course there is other information on the input that needs to be preserved.

Comment: Yes, good point.  Of course, preserving that data and replicating it on the new input would not be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The source is here:
https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/blob/master/src/dateinput/dateinput.js

At first glance there doesn't seem to be a destroy method, but you can perhaps just hide it and unbind focus and click on the element to effectively "remove" it?

Unfortunately it doesn't bind with a namespace, so you'd have to unbind all focus/click events on the input.  So that might not be viable if you have other behavior you need to retain.

Something like:

```
$('#value').dateinput('hide');
$('#value').unbind('click').unbind('focus');
```

Edit: Also

```
$('#value').data('dateinput', null);
```

If you want to attempt to toggle it back on.  I didn't peruse the source code enough to see if turning it back on after simply removing the event handlers would cause issues.